# Ubuntu keeps showing the install window after restarting from installing(Better Description below)

Tags: 12.10

Today I installed Ubuntu on my computer(Blank 1TB hard drive/no OS before) and when ever it's done installing it asks to re-boot/restart and I click re-boot but when ever it finishes it loads and asks, "Would you like to try Ubuntu or Install it". This has happend to me everytime I install(3 times). This is very complicated because I would like to just install once and keep all of the info I typed earlier, please answer it would be greatly appreciated.

P.S: Im running on ubuntu 12.10

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to eject the CD drive or unplug the USB stick you installed Ubuntu from after the installation has finished, and then reboot the machine.

Comment: my thoughts as well